# tensorflow2.0で廃止された placeholder と session について詳しく教えてください

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

いろいろなサイトを見ても `placeholder` と `session` の機能がよくわからなかったため、tensorflow2.0では直接コードを書けばいいと言われてもどうやって書けばいいのかわかりません。
説明だけではなくコードも例を用いて一緒に教えて欲しいです。
あとこの二つ以外にもtensorflowのアップデートで消えた機能を教えて欲しいです、お願いします。
tensorflowをダウングレードしたり以前の機能を引き継いだりするといったことはしたくありません。

Comment: 貴方が分からない事や直面している問題は具体的にどのようなものでしょう？ 例えばこんな解説記事を読めば(少なくとも)糸口になりますか？ [効果的な TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2), [TensorFlow 1 のコードを TensorFlow 2 に移行する](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate), [コードを TensorFlow 2 に自動的にアップグレードする](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade) そうで無ければこれらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容を改善・詳細化してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: とある参考書を読んでいるのですが、少し古いものなのでバージョン2.0を想定したものではありません　途中でtf.Sessionなるものが出てきて、module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'というエラーが出ました　そこでネットで調べたところこれをpythonのコードやnumpyで代用すればいいだけみたいなことが書いてあったので、tfのクラスを使わずに表現する方法を知りたいだけです　tensorflowのガイドラインも見たのですが、sessionとplaceholderをpythonの文法だけで表現する方法が載ってなかったのでこちらで質問しました

Comment: 今のところ主に貴方の感想ややったことの断片が書かれているだけで、他の人には「とある参考書」とは何か？そこにどのようなプログラムが書かれていたか？それの何処でどのような問題が発生しているか？どのような環境(PC・OS・IDEは何でその版数など)か？参考書が古い物なら同じ問題を扱った新しいTensorFlowに対応したものを探したのか？といったことの具体的な内容が伝わるようにはなっていません。それでは回答する人が状況を推測しようとしても情報が少なすぎて的確な助言・回答の出来る人はほとんど居ないのでは？それからそれらの情報はコメントに書くのではなく質問記事の本体を編集して見易く分かりやすいように記述してください。

Comment: わかりました　改善しておきます

Answer (score 0):

私自身は TensorFlow を使ったことがないので今回少し調べた程度になります。

---

[Tensorflow 2で1系記法のCNNを動かす方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/rawHam/items/626d9b119cbefcee1452) で紹介されている、以下のガイドが参考になりそうです。

[TensorFlow 1 のコードを TensorFlow 2 に移行する | TensorFlow Core](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

#### 方法1

> TensorFlow 2.x で 1.x のコードを未修正で実行することは、（contrib を除き）依然として可能です。
>
> ```py
> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf tf.disable_v2_behavior()
> ```
>
> しかし、これでは TensorFlow 2.0 で追加された改善の多くを活用できません。このガイドでは、コードのアップグレード、さらなる単純化、パフォーマンス向上、そしてより容易なメンテナンスについて説明します。

既存コードの以下 `import` 文を、上記の記述に置き換えるという事のようです。

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

#### 方法2

もしくは、前述の Qiita の記事に書かれている通り、既存コードの記述を `tf.compat.v1.*` の記述に変更する方法もあるようです。

> コード内の '1系' の列に該当するAPIを '2系' にある記載の通りに変更する。

| # | 1.x 系 | 2.x 系 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tf.placeholder | tf**.compat.v1**.placeholder |
| 2 | tf.Session() | tf**.compat.v1**.Session() |

他にも自動移行スクリプトなども用意されているようなので、[TensorFlow のガイド](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) に目を通してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます　placeholderとsessionは古いバージョンから引き継ぐというやり方が主流ということですね